# C++ use of HRESULT to return S_OK

Tags: c++, hresult

In legacy C++ code I'm working on, I noticed many methods that return HRESULT follow a practice of setting local variable to S_OK, then return it in the end of the method without changing it.

```
    HRESULT function()
    {
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;
        // do some stuff
        // none of which changes hr
        ...
        return hr;
    }
```

Are there any benefits of above code? Or can I safely refactor it to

```
    void function()
    {
        // do some stuff
        // none of which changes hr
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The refactoring your are proposing should work fine.  Just note that if there are any places in the code that use the return value of the function, you will get a compiler error, and you will have to fix those places.

Also note that in future versions of the code, it will be harder to add an error case to that function since you will have to reintroduce the return value and change all of the callers.  The original developer probably returned `S_OK` out of a sense of consistency, or an anticipation that the function might some day produce errors.

Comment: The second paragraph is a bit misleading. Changing the interface _always_ requires checking the callers, whether you throw an exception, set `errno` or return `HRESULT(E_OUT_OF_WIDGETS)`. And if the old code always returned `S_OK`, chances are a lot of callers don't check the error code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If your function **always** succeeds (or in other words never executes something that fails) you can get rid of it. So it depends on the content and what your function does. If you switch to `void` and you call your function, you will never know if the call "succeeded" or not.

Keep in mind that the body of the function **might** change in the future and when you suddenly need to return an error you have to update the calls to handle the errors properly.

Comment: Note also that the compiler is pretty good at doing this for you.

Comment: The answer does not cover optimization, it's a general answer for semantics and when he should use return-types to indicate that an error occurred.

Comment: Right, I'm just addressing OP's desire to refactor with a reminder that there probably is nothing to gain.

Comment: Ben Voigt: You commented on an answer, not on the OP's question, so it was hard to tell what you were talking about.